# Programmatically Change Domain of Email Address

Tags: email, imap, imaplib, email-client

I have a bunch of email addresses at abc.com, and I want to change them to the cde.com domain. Can I do it programmatically?

For example

```
example@abc.com --> example@cde.com
```

Comment: In what context? Something like x.replace(‘abc.com’, ‘cde.com’)?  Or do you mean like reconfigure server software?  That cannot be done through IMAP which is strict for accessing emails in an email box. It has no configuration capabilities whatsoever.

Comment: I mean create new emails with new domain

Comment: Well, you haven't told us what software or host you are using.  But, there's no standard way to do this. For example, for exchange, you may be able to do it with powershell cmdlets.  For a UNIX server, you may be able to use a bash script to modify the conf files, etc.  But at this point, you're talking about sysadmin stuff which is offtopic for StackOverflow (but may be on topic on serverfault)